# Light is dim orange

Tags: lighting

I rarely turn on my bedroom ceiling-fan light as I use other lights most of the time.

The last time I turned  it on using the pull string,  it came on with a dim orange color, as if it's only partly on.  Turning it off and on via the pull string produced the same results, as did toggling the wall switch. So then I went to the switch on the wall and turned off anything that was already turned on using the switch on the wall.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think she means "turn on"

Comment: Is it possible there is a remote control for the fan/light and it has accidentally been hit dimming the bulb?

Comment: Is there any sort of module in the fan canopy wired into the light circuit? (Turn the power off before poking around in there)

Answer (score 1):

- Turn off power to the light before doing the following, you may want to turn off
  the light circuit at your main electrical distribution board for extra safety:
- Check the bulb is seated firmly, for a screw-in light bulb, unscrew it,
  visually check the base of the bulb and the socket are clean, re-insert the bulb
  tightly. Turn it on and see if it is improved.
- Swap the bulb for a similar one in another light fitting and see if the problem follows the bulb or if the other, normally bright white, bulb is dim orange when placed in the ceiling-fan light socket.
- If the problem follows the bulb, dispose of it and buy a replacement.
- If the problem remains, call an electrician.